# Allignment of ext3 partition on LVM RAID volume group

Tags: linux, lvm, software-raid

I'm trying to add a partition on a LVM that resides on a RAID6 volume group and fdisk is complaining about the partition not residing on a physical sector boundry.

My question is, how do you calculate the correct starting sector for a partition on a LVM?  This partition will be formated ext3.  Would it be better to just format the LVM directly instead of creating a new partition?

```
Disk /dev/dedvol/backup: 2199.0 GB, 2199023255552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 267349 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 1048576 bytes / 8388608 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4e428f49

                     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/dedvol/backup1              63      267349  2146982827+  83  Linux
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

```
lvdisplay /dev/dedvol/backup 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/dedvol/backup
  VG Name                dedvol
  LV UUID                OV2n5j-7LHb-exJL-t8dI-dU8A-2vxf-uIicCt
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                2.00 TiB
  Current LE             524288
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     32768
  Block device           253:1
```

```
vgdisplay dedvol
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               dedvol
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               14.55 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              3815448
  Alloc PE / Size       3670016 / 14.00 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       145432 / 568.09 GiB
  VG UUID               8fBcOk-aXGx-P3Qy-VVpJ-0zK1-fQgy-Cb691J
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to add a partition on a LVM

You're doing it wrong. `man lvcreate`

Comment: +1. I was just in the middle of a much longer answer that was going to say the same thing.

Comment: The logical volume was created using "lvcreate -L2T -nbackup dedvol", so basically used all the defaults.  Are you saying you should not partition an LVM?  Or the LVM should have been created using custom chunk and strip sizes?

Comment: @John P, Dear John, why would one need partitioning a block device which is already a part of volume group? Since you're messing up basic concepts, I gently suggest you reading some intro to LVM-2. I hope en.Wikipedia.org's article could explain it quite well.

Answer (score 0):

"Would it be better to just format the LVM directly instead of creating a new partition?"

Yes!

Unless something is badly messed up, LVM autoaligns the LV start on the boundary but you also need to give the correct stripe and stride values for a Raid6 to achieve reasonable performance.

There's an online calculator for those values which you need to give during the filesystem format.
http://busybox.net/~aldot/mkfs_stride.html

The performance improvement can be worth doing it all over again. 
exception: when the array is just lightly used, then there's no improvement.

It's also possible to put them in the /etc/mk2efs.conf and then i.e. give the --fsprofile option during the kickstart install for RedHat / CentOS.
If you have the same kind of raid box everywhere it'll make sense. Otherwise no :)